# Partition Table problems. Primary within Extended?

Tags: partitioning

I am a new beee, and probably out of my depths.
I dual booted Ubuntu 12.04 on a machine already running windows.
I eventually dumped windows, and used Gparted running off of the Ubuntu Desktop LiveCD to expand my limited hard drive space.
In the process I believe I may have messed up my partition table.
I believe I have my primary partition running within an extended partition, which may be a problem ?
Exterior hard drives, which before I repartitioned would mount as read-only, now won't mount.

When entering  `sudo fdisk -l` I get this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 40.0 GB, 40000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4863 cylinders, total 78125000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9dc96e9e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda2            2048    78123007    39060480    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            4096    77080575    38538240   83  Linux
/dev/sda6        77082624    78123007      520192   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

UPDATE:   more info.

So, I am basically trying to figure out why my external drives won't mount anymore.
And I suspected that had to do with the repartitioning I did, and a messed up partition table, but perhaps I'm wrong.

I was asked in the comments for dmesg | tail before and after adding a device:

Before:

```
[332402.816025] parport0: FIFO is stuck
[332402.864049] parport0: BUSY timeout (1) in compat_write_block_pio
[332412.864070] FIFO write timed out
[332482.900041] parport0: FIFO is stuck
[332482.948067] parport0: BUSY timeout (1) in compat_write_block_pio
[332492.948038] FIFO write timed out
[332513.693367] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[332562.972045] parport0: FIFO is stuck
[332563.020056] parport0: BUSY timeout (1) in compat_write_block_pio
[332573.020100] FIFO write timed out
```

After adding a Western Digital HFS Plus external hard drive:

```
[332800.962790] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[332800.962800] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[332800.973591]  sdb: [mac] sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[332800.977422] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[332800.977432] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[332800.977439] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[332803.208062] parport0: FIFO is stuck
[332803.256075] parport0: BUSY timeout (1) in compat_write_block_pio
[332808.128065] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[332813.256036] FIFO write timed out
```

Also, when I pull up my partition table with my WD external drive attached, underneath the partition table I get this:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

The other external drive I am trying to connect is a Glyph GT050Q hfsplus which yields similar output.

Any help is great appreciated !

Thanks,

todd

Comment: please upload your gparted screenshot to `imgur.com` and post the link here.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? Are external hard drives not being mounted? Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: Here is the link to my gparted screenshot:http://imgur.com/bFkCwv0 .   As far as my specific question, yes external hard drives are now not mounting, as opposed to mounting as read-only before.   So, would this repartitioning have something to do with that?  and does my general partition table look Ok? Currently, no specific error is coming up when I connect external hard drives, but one will show up in Devices, but not mount.  The other doesn't show up in devices.   Thank you for any help, I'll try and reply quickly with any necessary info.

Comment: Your partition table is fine, if a bit unusual in that you have no primary partitions (except for the extended partition). You may have problems with your external drive(s), but you've presented no data on them. It's also possible you've got a problem with the auto-mounter. Try typing `dmesg | tail`, plugging in an external disk, and typing `dmesg | tail` again. New entries will relate to your plugging in the disk, and may contain clues about what's causing the problem.